# GitHub Actions- Create Artifact Container failed: Artifact storage quota has been hit. Unable to upload any new artifacts

Tags: workflow, github-actions, github-actions-artifacts

I have a GitHub workflow that creates artifacts (docker images and log files).

My repository is private and part of an organization.

I'm trying to upload new artifact with [upload-artifact action](https://github.com/actions/upload-artifact) but getting the error:
`Create Artifact Container failed: Artifact storage quota has been hit. Unable to upload any new artifacts`

I read there's a limit of 10GB per month for private repositories and no limit for public but I can't change my repository visibility.

I tried to use [gha-remove-artifacts action](https://github.com/c-hive/gha-remove-artifacts) and successfully removed all artifacts, but I still cant upload new artifacts.

Any ideas?

Comment: What does your billing say? If you go to your account Settings --> Billing --> Storage for Actions and Packages, what do you see? Docs: https://docs.github.com/en/billing/managing-billing-for-github-packages/viewing-your-github-packages-usage

Comment: I dont have access to the billing because the repository is in my organization account :/

Comment: If I recall correctly, that quota is related to bandwith to repository, not available storage space. It resets every month for free repos.

Answer (score 3):

In my case I just had to wait a little while before Github noticed that some artifacts had been deleted and then I could continue.

You can also specify when Github deletes old artifacts automatically for you in settings. Settings -> Actions -> General and find Artifact and log retention.

[image: Artifact and log retention]

Comment: When you say "a little while" is it 2 hours or 2 weeks?

Comment: Hey can you please define "a little while"? facing the same issue.